# How do I achieve .switchIfEmpty() type of method present in Reactive Framework with Mono/Flux with completable future?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, project-reactor, completable-future

```
Mono<String> getData1(){
  return someApiClient.getData();
}

Mono<String> getData2(){
  return someCacheClient.getData();
}

Mono<Object> callingMethod(){
  return getData2().switchIfEmpty(getData1());
}
```

How do I convert the "callingMethod" if my implementation is like this

```
CompletableFuture<String> getData1(){
  return someApiClient.getData().toFuture();
}

CompletableFuture<String> getData2(){
  return someCacheClient.getData().toFuture();
}

CompletableFuture<String> callingMethod(){
  // How to do it here? I am not getting any way. 
  // I need to achieve similar functionality like .switchIfEmpty here
}
```

I tried to search different articles online but did not find any. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Reactor types, `CompletableFuture` is able to handle `null` values, so you can use that to represent empty state and do action based on that:

```java
CompletableFuture<String> callingMethod(){
    return getData2()
        .thenCompose(cached -> cached == null 
            ? getData1() 
            : CompletableFuture.completedFuture(cached));
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response, but if you see in the reactor implementation, both the getData1() and getData2() are being executed simultaneously, but in this implementation you've proposed, getData1() will be called only after the response of getData2(); Is there any way to make it parallel too?

Comment: They are not executed simultaneously, switchIfEmpty is just a fallback which is triggered only if the first call wasn't empty. This is of course assuming that getData is a correctly implemented reactive method.